# How to write dsl to create scm sync for Perforce Stream with pathFilters?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, perforce, dsl, jenkins-job-dsl

We have a requirement where we need to write a DSL for syncing perforce stream with some filters. I couldn't find any example for dsl which syncs a perforce stream and adds some filters to exclude code builds if code commits are done to certain folders in the stream. The below code sets up the scm with the stream name..

```
pipelineJob('example444444') {
  definition {
    cpsScm {
      scm {
        perforceP4('creds') {
          workspace {
            manual('ws_name', '//streamname/mainline/abc/... //ws_name/...')
          }
          configure {
            node - >
              node / workspace / spec / streamName('//streamname/mainline')
          }
        }
      }
      scriptPath("abc/JenkinsFile")
    }
  }
}
```